# How can I vectorize this code in R? Maybe with the apply() function?

Tags: machine-learning, r, programming

I am really struggling to replicate the output of the dist() function in R code without using 1 or 2 for loops. (If you're wondering why I'm doing this, it's so that I can play around with the distance calculation, and also to improve my R skills - so please only solutions that involve R!)

Overview: matrix is passed to dist(), which calculates the Euclidean distance row-wise and outputs a full distance matrix of the distance between each row (e.g. distance between rows 1 and 50 will be in distancematrix[1, 50] and distancematrix[50, 1]). The fast code looks like this:

```
distancematrix <- as.matrix(dist(myMatrix, method="euclidean", diag = T, upper = T))
```

I have successfully produced the same output in R using the following code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(myMatrix)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(myMatrix)) {
    distancematrix[i, j] <- sum(abs(myMatrix[i,] - myMatrix[j,])) 
  }
}
```

However, using two nested for loops is much slower than using dist(). I have read a lot about using apply() to optimise slower for loops, but I haven't been able to get my head around it so far. I believe that at least one of the for loops is definitely avoidable by just outputting a vector, and dealing with it at the end. However, I cannot for the life of me work out how to remove both for loops.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it should be noted that the code you posted does not actually replicate the output of the `dist` function, because the line:

```
distancematrix[i, j] <- sum(abs(myMatrix[i,] - myMatrix[j,]))
```

does not calculate the Euclidean distance; it should be:

```
distancematrix[i, j] <- sqrt(sum((myMatrix[i,] - myMatrix[j,]) ^ 2))
```

Here are two solutions that rely on `apply`. They are simplified, and in particular do not take advantage of the symmetry of the distance matrix (which, if considered, would lead to a 2-fold speedup). First, generate some test data:

```
# Number of data points
N <- 2000
# Dimensionality
d <- 10
# Generate data
myMatrix = matrix(rnorm(N * d), nrow = N)
```

For convenience, define:

```
# Wrapper for the distance function
d_fun <- function(x_1, x_2) sqrt(sum((x_1 - x_2) ^ 2))
```

The first approach is a combination of `apply` and `sapply`:

```
system.time(
    D_1 <- 
        apply(myMatrix, 1, function(x_i) 
            sapply(1:nrow(myMatrix), function(j) d_fun(x_i, myMatrix[j, ]))
    )
)

   user  system elapsed 
 14.041   0.100  14.001
```

while the second uses only `apply` (but going over the indices, which are paired using `expand.grid`):

```
system.time(
    D_2 <- 
        matrix(apply(expand.grid(i = 1:nrow(myMatrix), j = 1:nrow(myMatrix)), 1, function(I) 
            d_fun(myMatrix[I[["i"]], ], myMatrix[I[["j"]], ])
        )
    )
)

   user  system elapsed 
 39.313   0.498  39.561
```

However, as expected both are much slower than `dist`:

```
system.time(
    distancematrix <- as.matrix(
        dist(myMatrix, method = "euclidean", diag = T, upper = T)
    )
)

   user  system elapsed 
  0.337   0.054   0.388
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to go through my code in so much detail! I eventually worked out a solution involving apply, but it wasn't as elegant as yours. My key question is whether apply is faster than an equivalent for loop - i.e. is it a question of optimisation or just of elegance?